# Find Sum of Two Numbers Using JavaScript in 1st one is manual entry and 2nd one is depend

Tags: javascript

i am using this code to get sum of 2 numbers

```js
function add() {
  var a, b, c;
  a = Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
  b = Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
  c = a + b;
  document.getElementById("answer").value = c;
}
```

```html
<input id="first">
<input id="second">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<input id="answer">
```

But I need to enter first value below 200
and automatically generate second value 5
and sum of 2 number 205

And if the first value is above 500 and below 1000, for example 800
the second value must be 10
and sum of 2 numbers 810

Based of first values second values are fixed like below

```
0 to 200 = 5
201 to 1000 = 10
1001 to 2500 = 20
2501 to 5000 = 50
5001 to 10000 = 1000
```

please let me know where i am wrong and please let me know correct code to get values

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. (or PHP, or arrays, or performance) Please try to learn the name of the language you're trying to write code in.

Comment: its java only and its already implemented in over project.. saying that tax if the total bill value below 200 tax addition 5 and sum of amount 205

Comment: *"its java only"* - That's not Java, it's JavaScript - the two are unrelated languages. *"please let me know where i am wrong"* - Well you can't be wrong when you haven't yet attempted the part you're asking about.

Comment: how to determanate fixed value depend on actual value

Comment: This website gets scarier everyday.

Comment: oho... i just asked to fix value depends on 1st value like if the 1st value is below 200 i need to add fixed 2nd value 5 and get total value 205 that's all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I cannot find any pattern on the given criteria for the value of `b`, I suggest addressing this problem using ranges (although it is tiring). The criteria, however, fail if `a` > 10,000.

In order to address this, I've added a simple "catch" of alerting the user of incorrect input, and not to continue with the addition of the numbers (since no value for `b` was generated).

Below is the code:

```js
function add() {
  var a, b, c;
  var within_range = true;
  a = Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
 
  if (a <= 200)
   b = 5;
  else if (a > 200 && a <= 1000)
   b = 10;
  else if (a > 1000 && a <= 2500)
   b = 20;
  else if (a > 2500 && a <= 5000)
   b = 50;
  else if (a > 5000 && a <= 10000)
   b = 1000;
  else {
   alert("First number must be less than or equal to 10,000.");
   within_range = false;
   document.getElementById("first").value = 10000;
  }
  
  if (within_range){
    c = a + b;
    document.getElementById("second").value = b;
    document.getElementById("answer").value = c;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="first">
<input id="second">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<input id="answer">
```

Comment: @alimbaronia Thanks a lot for your valuable answer it's worked and i completed my project successfully .. thanks once again